# jasmine integration tests with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jasmine, fabricjs

I'm trying to perform a integration test with Fabric.js's canvas. I'm clicking a div element and I expected that element to be added to the fabric canvas objects collection.

```
describe 'Image', ->
  beforeEach ->
    $('#add_image').trigger('click')

  it 'adds pre-existing image to the canvas', ->
    expect($('.slide-image-picker).is(':visible')).toBe(true) 
    $('.slide-image-thumbnail:first-of-type').trigger('click')
    expect(window.slide_gui_editors.slideshow_gui_canvas.toJSON().objects.length).toBe(1)
```

The first expect passes. The feature also works, however when I try to write a test for it the second expect line:

`expect(window.slide_gui_editors.slideshow_gui_canvas.toJSON().objects.length).toBe(1)`

is ran before Fabric.js is able to add the object to canvas. I also heard that using setTimeOut may give false positives.

Comment: Have you looked at [Jasmine Clock](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Jasmine_Clock) or [Asynchronous Support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)?

Comment: What version of Jasmine are you using?

Comment: We're currently using Jasmine 1.3, for purposes of being compatible with CircleCi. I'm thinking about using the runs, waits for, runs pattern on asynchronous support.